# Error when trying to install rvis

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I just started using ROS (groovy), and I'm trying to get rvis installed. I'm following the user guide.

When I try to install using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rviz
```

I am faced with the error

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-rvis
```

Please help! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66179/error-when-trying-to-install-rvis/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing I notice here is that the command is correct, but in the error output it says rviS, not rviZ. Sure you didn't accidentally put "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rvis" (with s instead of z) in as command and only wrote it right here?

---

Originally posted by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) with karma: 73 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-06-30**:
Oh dear, what a silly mistake! Thanks for pointing that out! :)

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-30**:
Glad I could help, in fact I knew this problem since I made the exact same mistake when trying to install rviz for the first time :P